# If $f$ is Riemann integrable on a closed interval, does its integral exists for any sequence of partitions with norm converges to $0$?

Tags: riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

It can ben shown that if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then $\int_a^bf\ dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ U(f, P_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ L(f, P_n)$ for **any** sequence of partitions of $[a, b]$ with norm (or mesh) converges to $0$.

Does the statement still hold if the continuity condition of $f$ is replaced by $f$ is Riemann integrable?

I find the statement still holds for $f$ being discontinuous at finitely many points so if it doesn't hold then any function for a counter-example has to be discontinuous at infinitely many points.

Comment: Yes, the statement still holds as Riemann and Darboux integrals are equivalent.

Comment: A typical definition of Riemann integral involves a limit when the norm/mesh of partition tends to $0$. When this definition is used then the result in question is essentially based on the fact that we can approximate both lower and upper Darboux sums via Riemann sums with arbitrary position. On the other hand another definition of Riemann integral uses limits via refinement of partitions. Under this definition the proof of the result is a bit tricky.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I've added the proof. If possible, please help to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and using the following definition of Riemann integral:

> We say that a bounded function $f: [a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable on $[a, b]$ if $U(f) = L(f)$. In this case we use the symbols
> $$
> \int_a^b\ f(x)\ dx\hspace{1em}\text{or}\hspace{1em}\int_a^b\ f\ dx
> $$
> to represent this common value.

I came up with the following sketch of proof.

Let $f$ be integrable on $[a, b]$ and $(P_n)$ be a sequence of partitions of $[a, b]$ with norm converges to $0$. We'll need to show that the following string of equalities hold:

$$
\int_a^b\ f\ dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ U(f, P_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ L(f, P_n).
$$

From the fact that $f$ is integrable and the definitions of supremum and infimum, it can be shown that there exists a sequence of partitions $(Q_n)$ such that:

$$
\int_a^b\ f\ dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ U(f, Q_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ L(f, Q_n),
$$

as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ ||Q_n||\to 0$.

Let $Q_n=\{x_0, x_1,..., x_{n_Q}\}$ where $x_{i-1}\lt x_i$ for $i=1, 2,..., n_Q$ and $M_k=\inf\{f(x): x\in[x_{k-1}, x_k]\}$, $m_k=\sup\{f(x): x\in[x_{k-1}, x_k]\}$. Then it can be shown that for each $M_k$, there exists $x^{(M)}_k\in [x_{k-1}, x_k]$ such that $f(x^{(M)}_k)=M_k$ or $\lim_{x\to x^{(M)}_k}f(x)=M_k$. Similarly, for each $m_k$, there exists $x^{(m)}_k\in[x_{k-1}, x_i]$ such that $f(x^{(m)}_k)=m_k$ or $\lim_{x\to x^{(m)}_k}f(x)=m_k$. Now for each $Q_n$, let

$$
d=\underset{1\le k \le n_Q}\min\{x^{(M)}_k-x_{k-1}, x_k-x^{(M)}_k, x^{(m)}_k-x_{k-1}, x_{k-1}-x^{(m)}_k\}.
$$

Next, choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $||P_m||\lt d/2$ for all $m\gt N$. This number $N$ exists since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ ||P_n||=0$. With such choice of $m$, it can be shown that there exist $y_{n_i}, y_{n_j}\in P_m$ such that $x_{k-1}\lt y_{n_i}\lt x^{(M)}_k\lt y_{n_i}\lt x_k$. And similarly, there exist $y'_{n_i}, y'_{n_j}\in P_m$ such that $x_{k-1}\lt y'_{n_i}\lt x^{(m)}_k\lt y'_{n_i}\lt x_k$.

From here, it's easy to see that $L(f, Q_n)\le U(f, P_m)\le U(f, P_m)\le U(f, Q_n)$. As $n\to\infty$, by Squeeze Theorem, we obtain

$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\ U(f, P_m)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\ L(f, P_m)=\int_a^b\ f\ dx,
$$

completing our proof.